# Magento 2: How to add popup on button click in admin?

Tags: adminhtml, javascript, magento2, jquery, requirejs

Can you explain how to add popup(modal window) on button click in the adminhtml?
I already create some phtml

```
<div id="messages">
<div class="messages">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCollection() as $reminder):
    ?>
    <div class="message message-notice notice">
        <div data-ui-id="messages-message-notice">Customer name - <?php echo $reminder->getCustomerName()
            ?>(Order ID #<?php echo $reminder->getOrderIncrementId() ?>); Date/Time - <?php echo $reminder->getDatetime()
            ?>; Due Date/Time - <?php echo $reminder->getDuedatetime() ?>; Assigned to User - <?php echo $reminder->getName() ?>;
            Note - <?php echo $reminder->getTitle() ?><button class="action- scalable primary">asd</button></div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

And I really need to know how to add modal action to the button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimal example

```
<div id="messages">
       <div class="message"> MessageContents 
           <button class="primary">ClickMe</button>
       </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
    ],
    function($, alert) {
       $('#messages').on('click', 'button.primary', function(event){
            alert({
               content: $(event.target).parent().text()
            })
       })
    }
);
// ]]></script>
</div>
```

Comment: :-  i want magento2 default pop up with content can you please share working code, please share full code else it will confuse us so

Comment: its working i  tried in front-end for that js is not included so through error

Comment: :- you answr is right but u need to add alert.js if you use in fronend